Power Automate Count Ocurrences of string
Given an output like this one below, which is obtained to a graph-api call.
"value": [
        {
            "userPrincipalName": "user@doamin.com",
            "assignedLicenses": [
                {
                    "disabledPlans": [],
                    "skuId": "4b585984-651b-448a-9e53-3b10f069cf7f"
                },
                {
                    "disabledPlans": [],
                    "skuId": "26d45bd9-adf1-46cd-a9e1-51e9a5524128"
                }
            ]
        },
[....]

I would to count the ocurrences for an skuId (4b585984-651b-448a-9e53-3b10f069cf7f) for example.
I tried splitting the by the string, and counting with no luck.
sub(length(split('@outputs','4b585984-651b-448a-9e53-3b10f069cf7f')),1)

Your syntax looks wrong and/or you haven't entered the above as expression. The expression should look similar to: sub(length(split(string(outputs('nameOfOutputStep)),'4b585984-651b-448a-9e53-3b10f069cf7f')),1)

You can try first Json Parsing and get assignedLicenses as an array to iterate then follow this link to get the count of distinct items: https://www.inkeysolutions.com/blogs/group-by-in-array-collections-in-power-automate-logic-apps/#:~:text=The%20'Group%20By'%20feature%20in,within%20a%20collection%20or%20array.

Unfortunately, the build in functions do not allow conditional parsing of the arrays for counts. But this can be achieved by a simple manipulation via filter array.
Here's how you can do it. Remember to parse the value object only. In case you have multiple objects, consider using a join t merge the license arrays first before filtering by skuid



Hello Laviza, can all this be run inside a ForEach loop?

Pass your Value Array to the foreach and usefilter array on 'Assigned License' array to fetch the SkuId needed. this way you will not go inside another loop and get the output you need.
